# Desktop shortcut for Java executable doesn't connect

Tags: java, .desktop

[EDIT: Typing `cd CashAdv` THEN ] Running `java -jar /home/bigaisdgood1/CashAdv/CashAdv.jar` in a terminal would run my program correctly and has no problems.

However, when I use that line of code in a .desktop shortcut as `exec=java -jar /home/bigaisdgood1/CashAdv/CashAdv.jar`, it would run, but not connect.

My Java program (CashAdv.jar) connects to Localhost by making a Connection String from a .txt file placed in the same folder.

I have a feeling it just doesn't see the .txt file, but I'm open to other possibilities.

- I've recently tried putting the .txt file in the same folder as the shortcut, with no effect.
- `Exec=cd /home/bigaisdgood1/CashAdv/ && java -jar /home/bigaisdgood1/CashAdv/FindDir.jar` is invalid, and returns an error when I use the shortcut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Path=` parameter in your desktop file  and `Type=Application`.

E.g.

```
Path=/home/bigaisdgood1/CashAdv
Type=Application
```

`Path` defines the working directory to run the program in, when entry of `Type` is Application.

Answer (score 0):

Make the shortcut/icon execute your application:

```
java -jar yourApplication.jar org.example.your.MainClass
```

I suppose, you need to add the precise location of the file, something like

```
#!/bin/sh
java -jar /home/fred/examp/Example234/Fredexample.jar
```

Comment: A `.desktop` file is no shell script, so I don't see why you use an `sh` shebang here...

Comment: Just making sure because I don't understand your suggestion. You want me to add my package stack, pointing it to the class that contains my `public static void main()` function?

Comment: Well, using the package stack and/or adding `#!/bin/sh` did not help. I did realize I may have entered the directory when I first used my terminal command. The answer as been edited to reflect this mistake. Thanks for trying.

Comment: I'm very sorry that it didn't help… Good luck!